# Automatically extract data from graph

Tags: graph, extract

I have a graph like:

[image]

I would like to generate a set of (x,y) pairs that correspond to points of this graph.

Maybe one for each horizontal pixel.

How would I go about doing this?

If I had the image in uncompressed bitmap format, maybe cropped to the actual graph, I could examine each vertical strip for the blackest point...

I would prefer to work in Python, but I'm interested in any technique.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question like this a while back. It should be fairly easy to detect the grid, from there you can get the pixel's coordinates relatively to the grid. However, it wasn't clear how to extract the numbers, which you need to do in order to get the the scale of the grid. Although, it might be possible fairly easily if you can match the font and font size (which might be possible via scaling). Otherwise, you'd have to enter the numbers manually.

To extract the grid, you'd start from the top right and move diagonally until you find the start of the grid. From there you can follow the vertical and horizontal lines (of the grid) until they end. This should allow you to say with fairly high probability where the outer rectangle of the grid is and what the x and y intervals of the grid are in terms of pixels. The blackest parts within the grid should do for finding the curve, but it may require some interpolation depending on how many data points you need/want.

It also may be useful to look into techniques for reversing anti-aliasing effects. Although, the uncompressed bitmap image may not need it.